# Display text on begin document

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I'm developing my own `documentclass`. How can I make some text appear on the beginning of each document with this class?

For now I'm working with this in the class:

```
\newcommand{\showAtBegin}{Text}
```

And in each document...

```
\begin{document}
\showAtBegin
```

But there has to be a neat way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need

```
\AtBeginDocument{Text}
```